# Connection Manager Compact 7 connectivity

Tags: winapi, wifi, windows-ce, wifimanager, windows-embedded-compact

I am working to create a wifi connectivity for a windows ce 7 device using connection manager. I am new to wince. Can anyone suggest how to establish a connection with a network. I actually wanted to have a list of available networks and to select a network from that. Please help me out in this situation. Awaiting your valuable responses. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You mean listing all the available wi-fi networks and then connecting to one of them?
Do you need to have a UI for this (to enter the wlan password etc.) or you'll provide your own UI and just need low-level function to activate the connection?